# Close iframe from child page with https

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iframe

I've been googling to figure this out but I just can't find any information on this.

I have a .aspx page that is displayed within iframe of a php parent page.

When a button is clicked on the .aspx page, I close the iframe to go back to the php parent page, and here's the code I use:

```
void btnDone_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "CLOSEWINDOW", "window.parent.postMessage('closeSurvey', '*');", true);
}
```

This was working just fine when I was testing the pages with http, but after I changed both the parent page and the .aspx page to https, this code is not working.

The developer of the parent page said he uses the same code to receive a message from the .aspx page, and no changes have made on the .aspx page either.

Am I missing something here to make it work with https as well?

Comment: 1) it is not possible to close an iframe, you're probably talking about a popup window. 2) If both domains are different AND on https, you won't be able to execute javascript coming from domain1 within a page coming from domain2

Comment: I've never really used an iframe but why is it not possible to close it? It is a modal iframe though.. The domain of parent site(php) is `https://www.XXX.com` and the child site(aspx) is `https://sub.XXX.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iFrame is a window inside a document, you don't "close" it as such... reading the word "modal" , I guess you're using some kind of lightbox system that actually creates an iframe on the fly to display outside source in a lightbox.

So what you actually try to do is closing a lightbox, and you won't be able to do it cause https will prevent you to access an element from the parent page from the child page, while http lets you do this.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now. So, there is no way or workaround to close the modal popup with https?

Comment: Not that I know. As a general matter, cross-domain stuff are sometimes  tricky, https security restrictions also, and when you mix both it's of course even more tricky :-/ I know it can be a pain in the a** , but that's perfectly justified security measures. While you want to use it for very legit reasons, other people could exploit it if it was allowed. There may be some ways to work around this though, by refreshing the whole page (the php one, not the one in the iframe) for example, but it's hard to say without seeing the code. Your only solution would be a workaround though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this library, it provides a call for an iFrame to remove itself from the parent page and works over https.

**https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer**